# DataTable Drag & Drop Columns

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, datatables

I am using [akottr dragtable](https://akottr.github.io/dragtable/) as jQuery Plugin to drag and drop a DataTables table.
This works very great and fast for the first result seen in the table.
But when I start navigating to the second page or any other page after the first one
only the column titles have changed for the drag and drop operation.
The cell values remain in the same order as before.
How can I make the drag and drop result work for all pages?

The current picture for page 1:

[image: The current picture for page 1]

And after navigating to page 2:

[image]

This is my JS code to initialize the drag and drop function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings) {
             var oTable = this;

             oTable.dragtable({
                        dragHandle:'.dragtable-handle',
                        maxMovingRows:1,
                        excludeFooter:true,
                        persistState: function(table) {
                            $('#myTable').DataTable().state.save();
                        }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my html table:

```
<table class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><div class="dragtable-handle">Action</div></th>
    <th><div class="dragtable-handle">Date</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>An Action</td>
    <td>2016-05-20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>An Action</td>
    <td>2016-05-14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>An Action</td>
    <td>2016-05-10</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you aware of ColReorder? -> **https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/**  / **https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html** The problem is that akottr dragtable is working on DOM tables, but you need something that can rearrange the internals as well (visible rows and hidden rows and all their  hidden columns)

Comment: I did not know. But my columns are dragged correctly for all pages. Only the row values do not fit.

Comment: hey @njlqay, yes - the column headers is reordered (they are visible in the DOM, all the time), but the columns themselves are not; the dragtable you are using have no chance of manipulating a paginated dataTable since most of it only exists in dataTables internals, not in DOM. So either you must refactor your dragtable so it uses the dataTables API to manipulate row and column data, or you could use the "native" ColReorder plugin. It is really easy to use, here is a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/817/**

Comment: I already tried but this native plugin does not work within my code :( I will take a look at the DataTables API...